# can not create xamarin.forms project from visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I cant create new xamarin.forms projects. visual studio 2015 gives me following error

[image]

- repaired my visual studio project,
- uninstalled and installed full visual studio software,

I can open existing xamarin projects and deploy successfully. but can not create new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what is the exact solution to this but you can follow these steps. It works for many people with this error.

1. Go to Add/Remove programs and open Visual Studio installer in modify mode
2. Remove Xamarin and related features
3. Reinstall Xamarin and related features.
4. Now open Visual Studio>>New Project>> Xamarin Project

Please keep in mind that you remove all Xamarin related tools from your Visual Studio.